# Replace latex equations in a PDF by rasterized graphics

Tags: graphics, equations, pdf

Is it possible to generate a PDF file with pdflatex where the equations are replaced by rasterized images? This would make conversion to other word processors formats easier.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! To your question: I hope not! And you will loose quality.  MS Word, for example, has a tool for equations. Perhaps you can use that?

Comment: I think you are still thinking in terms of Word processors. In TeX math is not a special object that you *add* but consists of actual font characters that are typeset. Hence you can't easily distinguish which is which for conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am very aware of the idea behind TeX math and that they are not objects. Unfortunately, I need to convert a very complex Latex document to the Word format. I achieved the best results by converting the PDF to .docx by using some tools, but the math equations still look very ugly. Therefore, I am looking for a method which replaces the equations by rasterized images already in the generated PDF. The conversion does not need to be perfect and the quality does not matter a lot, but the main formatting should be preserved.

Comment: You might be able to accomplish the entire conversion by compiling to HTML and then opening the HTML with Word. I think the first step will rasterize all the maths. Out of curiosity though, why do you need to convert to Word?

Comment: I tried compiling it to HTML but I am using a lot svg graphics and other special packages which makes it very difficult and would take a lot of time. I am writing a thesis and I want someone to proof read and correct it, but he is not very good with computers and wants a Word document which he can edit easily.